# Rotate vector along axis so that it lies on a plane

Tags: geometry, vectors, rotations, quaternions

Given a vector $v$, a rotation axis $r$ and a plane with normal $n$ (all three vectors are unit length), how can I obtain a rotation matrix or quaternion which rotates $v$ along $r$ so it lies on the plane? This can be expressed with the following equation:

$$qvq^{-1} \cdot n = 0$$

Where $q$ is a rotation quaternion along $r$. It can be written as follows in $(vector, scalar)$ form:

$$q = (r \sin \frac{\theta}{2}, \cos \frac{\theta}{2})$$

Now we have to find $\theta$.

It is acceptable to assume $\sin \theta \approx \theta$ in my specific case.

I quickly expanded the first equation (quite cumbersome to work with so it might be wrong) and I fell on a quadratic equation which makes sense because you can have two possible angles you can rotate about to make $v$ lie on the plane, or you can also have no solution in certain configurations.

I believe solving the quadratic is a possible solution to this problem despite being rather cumbersome. I wonder if there is another more elegant and stablished solution to this problem.

Thanks

Comment: $v$ and $r$ define a cone (a plane or line in the degenerate cases). Are you guaranteed that the plane is tangent to this cone? I.e., that it intersects the cone in one of the cone’s generators? If not, there’s no solution; if so, constructing a suitable matrix from the three given vectors is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @amd $v$ and $r$ are never parallel but could be orthogonal. The angle between them is fixed throughout my simulation. $r$ could be pointing in any direction though so the cone might not intersect the plane.

Comment: In that case, your first order of business is to determine whether or not a solution even exists. That’s a matter of computing the angle between $v$ and $r$ and comparing it to the angle between $n$ and $r$.

Comment: @amd It looks like cone-plane intersection would work, where the cone has its vertex in the origin and the plane also contains the origin. If the cone intersects the plane (excluding the vertex) then we have 2 lines and the possible solutions are the direction vector of the lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the plane passes through the origin, this problem comes down to finding the intersection of the plane with the nappe of the cone defined by $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf r$. This intersection will consist of up to two rays. Finding unit vectors in the directions of these rays is easy, from which vectors you can get the corresponding rotation angles or otherwise construct the rotation using your favorite method.

The first thing to do is to check whether or not there is a non-trivial intersection. This can be done by comparing the angles between the rotation axis $\mathbf r$, and $\mathbf v$ and the plane represented by $\mathbf n$, respectively, or, more conveniently, their cosines. Since we’re working with unit vectors, there will be an intersection when $$(\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf r)^2\le1-(\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf r)^2.$$

You can solve the cone-plane intersection problem directly, but I find it easier to transform everything so that the cone is aligned with the $z$-axis. A rotation will do the trick, but I think it’s faster and easier to use a Householder reflection instead. So, compute the transformation matrix $$H=I-2{\mathbf a\mathbf a^T\over\mathbf a^T\mathbf a}$$ where $\mathbf a=\mathbf r-(0,0,1)^T$. This is a reflection in the plane that bisects the angle between $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf r$. The advantage of using this transformation instead of a rotation is that $H=H^T=H^{-1}=H^{-T}$, so the same matrix can be used to transform back to the original coordinate system and to transform the normal vector $\mathbf n$. (That’s a covariant vector, so if points are transformed as $M\mathbf p$, it transforms as $M^{-T}\mathbf n$.) In practice, you might not need to construct this matrix, since you can directly compute $H\mathbf p=\mathbf p-2{\mathbf p\cdot\mathbf a\over\mathbf a\cdot\mathbf a}\mathbf a$ and only need to map a few vectors.

Set $\mathbf v'=H\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf n'=H\mathbf n$. The vectors that we’re looking for are the intersections of the transformed plane with the circle $x'^2+y'^2=1-(z_{\mathbf v}')^2$, $z'=z_{\mathbf v}'$ (i.e., the circle that is the intersection of the transformed cone nappe with the plane $z'=z_{\mathbf v}'$). Note, by the way, that $z_{\mathbf v}'=\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf r$. Following the method described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2387489/265466), reduce this to a two-dimensional problem by computing the intersection of the transformed target plane with $z'=z_{\mathbf v}'$ and project onto the $x'$-$y'$ plane. For the present problem, this amounts to multiplying the third coordinate of $\mathbf n'$ by $z_{\mathbf v}'$, i.e., $\mathbf l=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,z_{\mathbf v}')\,\mathbf n'$. Proceeding as in the linked answer, find the intersection of this line with the circle $x'^2+y'^2=1-(z_{\mathbf v}')^2$ and project back onto the $z'=z_{\mathbf v}'$ plane to get unit vectors $\mathbf w_1'$ and $\mathbf w_2'$ (which might be identical).

With these vectors in hand, you can proceed in several ways to derive the corresponding rotations. The rotation angle required to take $\mathbf v$ to $\mathbf w_i=H\mathbf w_i'$ is just the negation of the angle between the projections of $\mathbf v'$ and $\mathbf w_i'$ onto the $x'$-$y'$ plane (negated because $H$ is orientation-reversing), and once you have this angle, you can use well-known formulas to construct an appropriate rotation matrix or quaternion. You could also construct a rotation matrix $R'$ in the transformed frame, which will just be a rotation about the $z'$-axis, and then transform it back to the original coordinate system: $R=HR'H$. (This is another instance in which the identity $H=H^T=H^{-1}=H^{-T}$ comes in handy.)

For numerical stability, you might want to align the rotation axis with one of the other coordinate axes. The best choice in that regard is the standard basis vector $\mathbf e_i$ which maximizes $\|\mathbf r-\mathbf e_i\|$. Getting back to the above solution is a simple matter of permuting coordinates after applying $H$, but be sure you keep track of orientation changes if you’re going to use the computed rotation angles directly.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to write the detailed answer. Took me a while to fully understand but now I think I get it. I don't understand why you squared the dot products in the inequality though. Wouldn't $\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf r \le 1 - \mathbf n \cdot \mathbf r$ be enough?

Comment: @xissburg No, because we really want to compare the absolute values in case the angle between $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf r$ is $\gt\pi/2$ or the normal is pointing the “wrong” way. Also, we’ve got to square one of the terms, anyway, and computing another square is generally less expensive than taking a square root: $\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf r$ is the *sine* of the angle to be examined ($\mathbf n$ is perpendicular to the plane), so the cosine would be $\sqrt{1-(\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf r)^2}$.

Answer (score 3):

The thread is rather old (almost 4 years ago), but I want to present rather a straightforward solution to the problem.

The task is to find such rotation angle $\theta$ that vector $v$ after rotation $R(r, \theta)$ will lie on the plane with given normal $n$.
Transformed vector $v' = R\,v$ will lie on the plane only if it is perpendicular to plane normal $n$

\begin{equation}
v' \cdot n = 0.
\end{equation}

As it was mentioned in [amd's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2390645/911818) the equation has the solution(s) only if

\begin{equation}
(v\cdot r)^2 \le 1 - (n\cdot r)^2.
\end{equation}

Next, one can use the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle)

\begin{equation}
R(r, \theta)  = \cos \theta + \sin\theta \,[\,r\,]_\times + (1-\cos\theta) r \otimes r,
\end{equation}

and apply this to the first equation to obtain the trigonometric equation for $\theta$

\begin{equation}
\cos\theta\, (v\cdot n) + \sin\theta(r\times v)\cdot n + (1-\cos\theta) (v\cdot r)(n\cdot r) = 0.
\end{equation}

The last step is to solve this trigonometric equation.
It can be done via substitutions, i.e. $x = \cos\theta$, but I will skip this part (I used software for symbolic calculation to solve it implicit).
The solution is as follows

\begin{equation}
\theta_\pm = \tan^{-1}\left(x_\pm,y_\pm\right)
\end{equation}
where $\tan^{-1}$ is [inverse tangent function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2), and the coefficients:

$x_\pm = \frac{C(C-A)\pm\sqrt{B^2[(A-C)^2 + B^2 - C^2]}}{(A-C)^2 + B^2}$,

$y_\pm = \frac{(C-A)x_\pm -C}{B}$,

$ A = v\cdot n$,

$ B = (r\times v)\cdot n$,

$ C = (v\cdot r) (n \cdot v)$.

To validate the equations, I prepare a small demo using UnityEngine, which is avialible [**here**](https://github.com/andywiecko/RotateVectorToLieOnPlane).