# Finding Orthogonal Vectors in a Plane

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I find orthogonal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that lie in a plane created by the equation below:

$$x_1-2x_2+4x_3=0$$

Thanks,

Comment: $$\vec{n}=(1;-2;4)$$ is such a vector

Comment: or $$[-2;1;4]\times [0;2;1]$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner $(1; -2; 4)$ is orthogonal **to** the plane. The OP wants orthogonal vectors that lie **in** the plane.

Comment: ok i misread this question

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner So did I, probably due to the misleading title...

Answer (score 3):

A plane has the equation
$$a x_1+b x_2+c x_3=d$$
The normal to this plane is $n=[a,b,c]$.

So you want two vectors perpendicular to each other, and perpendicular to $n$.

Pick any vector $v_0$ not parallel to $n$. Then $v_1=n\times v_0$ and $v_2=n\times v_1$ are the sought-after vectors. (see [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product))

Answer (score 0):

From the equation of the plane, we find that the vector $\mathbf n=(1,-2,4)^T$ is normal to the plane. Every vector that’s orthogonal to $\mathbf n$ lies in the plane. Three obvious choices are $(2,1,0)^T$, $(4,0,-1)^T$ and $(0,4,2)^T$. (In general, given a non-zero vector $(a,b,c)^T$, at least two of $(0,c,-b)^T$, $(-c,0,a)^T$ and $(b,-a,0)^T$ are non-zero and orthogonal to the original vector.) Choose any one of these for your first vector and the cross product of $\mathbf n$ with the chosen vector for the other.

Essentially, you’ve being asked to find an orthogonal basis of $\mathbf R^3$ such that two of the basis vectors span the given plane. In $\mathbb R^3$ you can take advantage of cross products to do this. In higher-dimensional spaces, you’ll have to do something a little different. In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1909570/265466), Marc van Leeuwen describes an easy way to construct such a basis for a hyperplane in $\mathbb R^n$.