# How to calculate transformation matrix from one plane to another?

Tags: matrices, vectors, linear-transformations, transformation, matrix-equations

Let's consider the basic 3D coordinate system. I have a plane **P** defined with three points **A(xa,ya,za)**, **B(xb,yb,zb)** and **C(xc,yc,zc)**. 
I have some object (a mesh - set of vertices and triangles) in the coordinate system and the plane P is actually a cutting plane, which should split the mesh in two slices.

I will need to transform the mesh (to rotate it) relative to a fixed cutting plane (for example, plane `z = 0` is the best fit - I need all values for z value to be equal, in order to do the cutting).

So as a first step in my algorithm, what I will need to do, is to transform (with transformation matrix **R**) the plane P to the plane `z = 0`, to use this plane as a reference for cutting the mesh and then to apply the reverse transformation matrix **R'** so that the mesh slices are transformed backed at their original locations.

My question now is: is it possible to calculate the transformation matrices **R** and **R'**, based on the three points **A**, **B**, **C** on the plane **P**?

My guess is that I can do the following (calculate the normal vector by using the points A, B, C):

```
diffVectorBA = B - A = (xb-xa, yb-ya, zb-za);
diffVectorCA = C - A = (xc-xa, yc-ya, zc-za);
vectorNormal = crossProduct(diffVectorBA, diffVectorCA)
             = (diffVectorBA.Y * diffVectorCA.Z - diffVectorBA.Z * diffVectorCA.Y,
                diffVectorBA.Z * diffVectorCA.X - diffVectorBA.X * diffVectorCA.Z,
                diffVectorBA.X * diffVectorCA.Y - diffVectorBA.Y * diffVectorCA.X);
```

but after calculating this, I'm not sure how to proceed and how to calculate **R** and **R'**?

Comment: You can do this “cutting” without any transformations at all. If the equation of the plane is $ax+by+cz+d=0$, then for *any* point, the sign of the quantity on the l.h.s. tells you on which side of the plane the point lies. If you really want to do this via transformations, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1909570/265466) for an easy-to-construct reflection that will also do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructing an appropriate rotation for this application is easy if you remember two things: the columns of a transformation matrix are the images of the basis vectors, and the inverse of a rotation matrix is its transpose (which you’ve already used in the question.) If you have a right-handed orthonormal basis $(\mathbf u,\mathbf v,\mathbf w)$ of $\mathbb R^3$, then the matrix $R=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf u&\mathbf v&\mathbf w\end{bmatrix}$ represents a rotation that maps the standard basis vectors onto these. So, if $\mathbf w$ is parallel to the normal of your plane, $R^T$ will rotate it so that it is parallel to the $x$-$y$ plane. You’ll probably want to translate first so that it is mapped *onto* the $x$-$y$ plane to make the “cut” simpler. You’ve got the plane’s normal $\mathbf n=(B-A)\times(C-A)$. An orthonormal basis that fits the bill is $$\mathbf w = {\mathbf n\over\|\mathbf n\|}, \mathbf u={B-A\over\|B-A\|}, \mathbf v=\mathbf w\times\mathbf u.$$  You can also find a simple way to construct a reflection that maps $\mathbf n$ to the $z$-axis [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1909570/265466). The change of orientation is irrelevant since you’re only care about the $z$-coordinates after the transformation, and an advantage of a reflection is that it is its own inverse.

However, transforming your data points in order to do this partitioning is unnecessary. An equation of the partitioning plane is $\mathbf n\cdot(\mathbf x-A)=0$. For points not on the plane, the expression on the left-hand side of this equation is proportional to the signed distance of $\mathbf x$ from the plane. The sign tells you on which side of the plane the point lies: if positive, then it’s on the side toward which $\mathbf n$ points; if negative, it’s on the opposite side from $\mathbf n$. (If zero, the point, of course, lies on the plane.) So, in order to partition your mesh, you need only check the sign of $\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf p-\mathbf n\cdot A$ for each point $\mathbf p$ of your mesh.

Comment: can you please check this question as well: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531184/how-to-calculate-transformation-matrix-from-plane-p-to-the-planes-x-0-and-y-0?