# How to construct a rotation matrix from only one axis?

Tags: matrices, rotations

The objective is to construct a rotation matrix defining a Cartesian frame B with respect to frame A. We only know one axis of B. In more details I know the Z-axis of B. Thus, the objective is to get X and Y axes such that the rotation matrix is $^AR_B= (X~ Y ~Z)$.

If we assume the orientation around Z is not constrained, how to get X and Y? One solution would be to solve $X^TZ=0$ and $\|X\|=1$ which leads to a circular solution. But is there not a straight forward manner to get X and Y?

Comment: Is Gram-Schmidt straightforward enough?

Comment: @DavidK More details pls?

Comment: Do you know Euler angles? It will help you to visualize better. [Take a look at this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Definition_by_intrinsic_rotations). By two rotations you can make the $Z$ axes of two frames to coincide. A third rotation can be done so that the $X$ and $Y$ axes coincide.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In fact I can directly use cross product. I just take any vector $V$ different from Z. Then set $X=Z\times V/norm$. Then $Y=Z \times X$, which solves my problem.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909536/basis-to-hyperplane, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710103/algorithm-to-find-an-orthogonal-basis-orthogonal-to-a-given-vector/712030#712030, and many other related questions. Yours is essentially a duplicate of them.