# Eigendecomposition of rank-deficient rank-$1$ update

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, projection-matrices, hamel-basis

I have a matrix of the form $C = I - a a^T$. In this particular case, $a$ is a constant vector with value $1/\sqrt{N}$, where $N$ is the rank of $I$ (number of columns). For $I = eye(5)$, $N$ will be 5.

I am trying to find a matrix $U$ such that $C = U U^T$. I can do this using eigenvalue decomposition.

I have found "Some Modified Matrix Eigenvalue Problems" from *Golub* and looks very promising, as it shows how to compute eigenvalues for the exact same kind of matrices that I have. It says that when $a$ has all values different than 0, the eigenvalues of C can be computed as the zeros of

$$ 1 - \sum_i^N {\frac{u_i^2}{d_i - \lambda}}$$

Following that formula, in my particular case I can write

$$ 1 - N {\frac{1/N}{1 - \lambda}} = 0$$
which is only true for $\lambda = 0$. Matlab says that I have $N-1$ more eigenvalues that are equal to 1.

Assuming that I have 1 eigenvalues which equals to 0 and $N-1$ which equals to 1, I have tried to compute the eigenvectors using "Rank-One Modification ofthe Symmetric Eigenproblem" from *Bunch, Nielsen and Sorensen* but I am not sure I can use that. In Section 4 they define $D_i$ as 
$$D_i = D - \tilde{d}_i I$$
with D being the singular values of the original matrix (called $B$ in this last paper). In my particular case, I can have two different possible values for $D_i$: An indentity matrix, which is associated with the first eigenvalue, which is 0, or a null matrix, associated with the other eigenvalues. They said that "Theorem 1 implies that $D_i$ is nonsingular" which in my particular case is not true at all.

I am not sure if I can use all this theory given that my updated matrix is not rank complete.

Do you have any idea on how could I find a closed form for $U$?

Edit: Fix a typo

Comment: a = (w, w, w..., w) with w= 1/√N and N =rank(I)

Comment: Please provide links to papers. DOI, please.

Answer (score 1):

For general $a$, such a decomposition exists if and only if $\|a\|_2\leq 1$. This is satisfied in the special case above.

We can compute an eigen-decomposition and the matrix $U$ directly. Clearly, $a$ is an eigenvector of $C$ with the associated eigenvalue $1-a^Ta\geq 0$. The remaining eigenvectors can be taken from the orthogonal complement of $a$ and correspond to repeated eigenvalue $1$ (of multiplicity $N-1$). So if we take an orthonormal matrix
$$
V:=\left[\frac{a}{\|a\|_2},\tilde{V}\right]
$$
and diagonal
$$
D:=\begin{bmatrix}1-a^Ta & 0\\ 0 & I_N\end{bmatrix},
$$
then $A=VDV^T=UU^T$ with $U:=VD^{1/2}$.

There's also a [simple way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710103/algorithm-to-find-an-orthogonal-basis-orthogonal-to-a-given-vector/712030#712030) based on Householder reflections which provides an explicit formula for $V$ if the specification above is not explicit enough.